# How the information from different resources are used in calculating the reputation score of a domain name in whoisxml (domain reputation API)?

Tags: malware, domain

I'm trying to obtain the reputation score of a domain name from whoisxml. There are some resources listed in their website such as the website content and it relation to other domains, and host configuration or Reverse IP lookup that the score is calculated based on them. I'm wondering if there is more information about each one of these resources somewhere e.g how the Configuration of the name server is used in calculating the score?